# Per user salts and cross-user hash attacks

Tags: security, hash, sql-server-2008-r2, passwords, salt

We hash users passwords (in a .net web application) with SHA2 & the following salts:

- **Application salt** - stored outside the database (in our case the web applications web.config as an encrypted string) - this is passed to stored procedures that are involved in logging in, creating new users and changing passwords etc.
- **Per user salt** - a SQL uniqueidentifier - currently stored in the user table - generated automatically at insert time using default `(CONVERT([char](36),newid(),(0)))`
- **Database salt** - a salt stored in a settings table within the database.
- **Password** - and of course the users password.

Whilst this helps with rainbow & dictionary attacks etc I was thinking of what would happen if someone did find a hole in our security and managed to run an update statement against the database – specifically - what would stop a user from registering with our site with a password they know then replacing the salt & hash on an admin account with their salt and hash - thus giving them full admin access to our site / application?

Is this a risk we should realistically worry about? If so, does it have a technical term / Standard prevention technique?

I was thinking of involving the users ID (an integer in our case) in the hash in some way - just curious what the best practice is on this or are we over thinking things?

**PS:** I know SHA2 isnt an ideal hash to use for passwords and that slower hashing methods such as BCrypt are preferred, this was a decision made before my involvement on the project

**PS:** Our web application (and its application key) are heavily firewalled from the SQL server - only one port is open between them & that's used for SQL)

Comment: There's really no relationship between how you store password hashes and SQL injection. The purpose of using salted hashes is to make a dump of your passwords useless to an attacker. If you allow attackers to execute arbitrary SQL, having a password changed is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly I think you are over-thinking things. If a malicious user is in the position to run an update query against your users table, they most likely have equal access to the other tables in the database. Again, most likely permissions are also stored in said database and it would be easier to run another query to grant themselves the appropriate permissions, rather than muck with taking over an existing admin's account. Or, simply change whatever data they wanted directly in the database and forget the front end entirely.

Therefore I would say once a user has access to the database (via SQL injection or otherwise) all bets are already off and they can do whatever they like.

Note the reason for salting a hash is simply to make the dump of passwords valueless. That is, if (when?) a user re-uses their password for another site and it were not salted, looking up the obtained hashed value in a dictionary (a so-called rainbow table) would provide the *plaintext password* which could then be used on another site to impersonate the user. Salting the hash eliminates this "reversibility" of using a rainbow table to look up the value. Knowing the salt does give the attacker a leg up, but they still need to brute-force their way into getting the matching password. Adding an unknown application-wide salt makes the process much more difficult, although it would still be possible with millions of accounts and a lot of brute-force or sheer luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're certainly correct in considering the risk of arbitrary SQL injection as a show-stopper in terms of any password security and/or application security.

In a breach of database security (either by someone stealing a SQL dump or having arbitrary SELECT access to your data) the preventative measure of hardening stored passwords allows some assurances with regard to the privacy of passwords of your end-users and also some application security in that the SELECT won't lead directly to a password that can be stolen and used to login.

However, if a SELECT statement is accessible, that can be paired with other SQL mechanisms to, for instance, write arbitrary web-shells or other files server-side that could potentially allow your attacker to influence the application code in such a way they could MITM the user passwords upon login (since the crypto is happening server-side on the hashing).

The ultimate answer to your question is, SQL injection is a *very* serious issue and adding layers such as web application firewalls (WAFs) or a SQL proxy (GreenSQL comes to mind) can provide an advantage when code is deployed without proper SQL security.